# How To Find Speed/Size Of Laptop Fan

Tags: fan, cooling, toshiba-laptop

I have a Toshiba Satellite P755-S5320, I have scoured through my documentation and can find out anything (almost) about the laptop except is the cooling fan 80MM or 120 MM?

Comment: You can determine the size by using a ruler and measuring the size.

Comment: @Ramhound - I do not have the laptop beside me atm

Comment: You need to go get the laptop and place it besides you.  You then need to measure the size of the fan with the ruler.  If you have money to burn you could just purchase a 80MM and 120MM then return the fan you don't need.

Comment: Doesn't look like any kind of standard fan to me - [full takepart](http://www.irisvista.com/tech/laptops/Toshiba-Satellite-P755-P755D-P750-P750D/disassemble-P755-1.htm) and [close-up pic](http://www.irisvista.com/tech/laptops/Toshiba-Satellite-P755-P755D-P750-P750D/body-big/Toshiba-Satellite-P755-disassembly-23.jpg)

Comment: Bit of further Googling found this - http://www.amazon.com/KSB06105HA-Compatible-Laptop-Fan-FAN01/dp/B005DEL85E  Amazing thing, Google, isn't it?  ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin - You linked to a HP compatible fan.

Comment: I linked to one that a) looks the same minus the metal cover & b) has the same part number. Just start typing KSB061… into Google & see how many hits you get for that fan or similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual answer, as mentioned in comments is "get a ruler & measure it."

The more logical answer is find a take-apart guide, such as http://www.irisvista.com/tech/laptops/Toshiba-Satellite-P755-P755D-P750-P750D/disassemble-P755-1.htm
with pictures -

[image]

…then Google the part number - KSB06105HA - & see what comes up
eg [http://www.amazon.com/KSB06105HA-Compatible-Laptop-Fan-FAN01/dp/B005DEL85E](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005DEL85E) & many others.

That way, you never need to actually ever know the dimensions.

Comment: Even though when you click the link it shows its for an HP it will not make a difference?

Comment: Computer manufacturers rarely use completely custom parts in their builds, they use what is available from the component manufacturers at the time. As far as I'm aware, other than the metal cover, the two are identical. Without seeing it in my hand, I can't tell how easy it is to just swap that cover to the new fan, but my guess would be... very simple.